# When to use protected and private attributes?

Tags: python, oop

Disclaimer: I don't have a special knowledge about OOP, I tried to learn from other posts but it's not so clear for me.

So when I define a class, when to make an attribute protected and when to make it private. Do you have some rule of thumbs?

What confuses me is this principle of protected/private. If I don't need to access the attribute from outside the class, well, I simply won't access it (I mean, it's up to me!), I will access it only when I need. I feel like this private/protected attribute principle is like some protection against some metaphysical forces.

Comment: Python doesn't *have* protected or private access, for reasons similar to your own.

Answer (score 1):

Some languages strictly prevent you from accessing private attributes, but Python (kind of for the reasons you've mentioned) doesn't do that.

As you said, "(I mean, it's up to me!)" - The only occasion this kind of protection is useful is when working with a team (or coming back to a project after a few months), and forgetting which attributes you're meant to be allowed to access from outside that class or not.

It is convention to prepend variables that are internal-only with a `_`, just to remind you to double check it's ok before referencing it from outside.

More info in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private).

Comment: And if I change an attribute from public to "protected" using the underscore, do I need to define a property and a setter?

Comment: You don't ever really *need* to use properties or setters, they are optional extras that let you call a method as if it was an attribute. They are niceties for other components using your class, and as a private attribute isn't getting used by anything external, it doesn't make much sense to do for them either.

Comment: If I need to tell team members that only access is allowed and not modification, what to do  in this case?

Comment: Then use a @property or getter-method, pointing to an internal private variable

Answer (score 0):

A language like Java has strict protection against inappropriate access (but Python doesn't, as explained in other answers).

**Java Example**

[Java's ArrayList](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L141) is a good example of the use of private and protected members.

Looking at the linked source code, you will notice:

- `private int size;` -- `size` is private because we don't want users fiddling with the `size` of the `ArrayList` directly. They are already able to `add`, `remove`, and `clear` the List, so the `ArrayList` class should maintain its own `size` from these methods. Allowing the user to manipulate `size` will only open the possibility of causing the `size` to be incorrect (and thus causing an inconsistent data structure). Note that the user has the `public int size()` method, so they are able to **access** the value of `size` at any time, but not assign a new value to it.
- `protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`  -- This one is `protected` because there are already other ways of removing a range of elements from an ArrayList (specifically using `arrayList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).clear();`, which eventually invokes `ArrayList`'s `removeRange` method). Preventing unrelated classes from doing the same thing in multiple ways encourages cleaner and more consistent code - but to prevent redundancy, nested and child classes can still access these protected methods.

**Python Example**

While you *can* follow the same practices in Python, the language doesn't strictly prohibit access. Here is an example showing how you can still access protected and private members:

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self.__y = y

s = MyClass(1, 3)
print(dir(s))
print(s._x)
print(s._MyClass__y)
```

Output:

```
['_MyClass__y', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_x']
1
3
```

As you can see, `__y` was detected as private and changed into `_MyClass__y`, and `_x` can still be accessed as `_x`, even though it's marked as protected with the underscore.